# Getting no login prompts when trying to access private content, getting "Page not found" instead

Tags: joomla-3.x, redirect, acl

I have private content on the site, and I want "non-registered" users to be redirected to the login page when they try to access the private content, without using any extensions.

I have tried multiple ways:

1. setting access level of the link as public and
2. the private resource as registered and
3. some other things

However, accessing the private content in this way is throwing off a "404". Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: Welcome HopeScott, please take our [tour].

Comment: Are you able to access the content when logged in as super user? Have you made any changes to permissions? Normally a 404 message is when content has been removed or moved to another URL

Comment: I can access the content when logged in as a super user and also, the content wasn't moved in any way.  I only assigned it "Registered" access level.

Comment: Can you say what you're displaying on the page - is it a single article for example? Setting the access level of the menuitem to registered should mean that visitors to the site who are not logged in will not see that menuitem. If you set the access level of the menuitem to public and the single article to registered then I would expect visitors to see a message "Error You are not authorised to view this resource." when they clicked on the menuitem, rather than getting 404. You can select which pages you display the Joomla login module on to allow users to log in on such pages.

Comment: This is not an expected behavior and although it's not 100% impossible (I haven't tested with the latest version) but a bug of that size would be hard to exist in Joomla core... So there should be something on your configuration/setup that causes this - but it's hard to get a clue - such issues usually need hands-on troubleshooting.